# What is does (millis) mean inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:

**1:** What is the "millis" in the parenthesis? Is it milliseconds and if so is it a timer or something else?

**2:** Does it mean `if(lastTime ) mean if(lastTime == 0 )?`

Thanks in advance!

```
let lastTime;

function callback(millis) {
    if(lastTime) {
        update(millis - lastTime) /1000;
    }
    lastTime = millis;
    requestAnimationFrame(callback);

}
```

Comment: it's just a name for the parameter. as the documentation is missing, we can just guess what it stands for

Comment: since the function seems to deal with time I'd wager it stands for 'milliseconds'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`millis` is a parameter (for the `callback()` function), and it refers to some number of milliseconds.

The function *appears* to be calculating the time in seconds since it was last called, but if so, there is a bug:

```
update(millis - lastTime) /1000;
```

Presumably, `update()` is supposed to be invoked with the elapsed time in seconds, but that should instead look like this:

```
update((millis - lastTime) / 1000);
```

The current version, on the other hand, is attempting to divide the *return value* of `update()` by 1000, which is at best a no-op.

Without seeing more of the code, it's difficult to see what exactly the purpose is. For example, the last line...

```
requestAnimationFrame(callback);
```

... seems kind of strange, as the function essentially repeatedly calls itself, most of the time without even having the `millis` argument provided. It's possible the purpose is to notify `update()` anytime it is invoked outside of a `requestAnimationFrame()` request, along with how much time had elapsed since it was last called, but there's simply not enough code here to tell what its purpose is within a larger program.

Comment: Thank you for your help!